# SASS + media queries + Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, modal-dialog, media-queries

I can't seem to find the right way to simply change the modal body background color in case of a **max-device-width of 480px**.

What am I doing wrong? (the final purpose is not to change the body color of course)

```
.modal.blue.modal-fixed {
    .modal-body{
        color: map_get($colors, 'light');
        max-height: calc(100vh - 85px);
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: map_get($colors, 'dark-blue');
    }

    @media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px){
        .modal-body{
          background:#fff;
        }
     }
}
```

Edit: Note that it works if I try

```
min-device-width : 480px
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
@media (max-width: 480px)
```

instead of

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px)
```